# Raspberry pi 4 gives vertical color lines on bootup

Tags: boot, pi-4, display, boot-issues, ubuntu

I am using a Raspberry pi 4 model B 4GB with ubuntu 20.04 installed on a 32GB memory card and when I booted, I got a display with vertical color lines. I tried using multiples displays and all results are the same. The red light is on and the green one is flashing alright. It was working alright for a week and suddenly started giving these lines.

[image]

Comment: Most likely a hardware related issue. Can you try with another power source? Then try with a same raspberry with newly flashed new SD card. Also is it connected over HDMI/DVI/VGA? Try other ones as well.

Comment: what changed recently

Comment: I tried 3 power sources, with & without the SD card, with VGA on my PC monitor and HDMI on my TV, same result. It started happening when I tried to use a Power bank with same power requirement as source.

Comment: Try adding `hdmi_safe=1` to `/boot/config.txt`.  That it does this with VGA implies that won't work, of course, but you might as well try because otherwise the implication is "busted GPU".